# This custom wordpress loop is giving strange results. Can someone please correct it?

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

The following query is expected to display four posts of category number 28. What it is doing us that it's showing three posts of category number 28 and one post of category number 32. I have no idea what is wrong with the code.

```
                <?php $CstmLoop = new WP_Query(

                array('cat=28','posts_per_page' => 4)

                ); ?>


                <?php if ( $CstmLoop->have_posts() ) : ?>

                <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
                <?php while ( $CstmLoop->have_posts() ) :$CstmLoop->the_post(); ?>



                    <?php

                            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format());


                    ?>




                <?php endwhile; ?>
                <?php else : ?>

                    <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' ); ?>

                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php WP_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

But here is the interesting part - if I do not use an array and simply pass 'cat=28' as the only argument, it displays all the posts of category 28.

Comment: Is the other category (32) a child category of category 28? Then it would be as per definition `Display posts that have this category (and any children of that category), using category id` (from [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query))

Comment: Thanks a lot. No, it's not a child category. But category 32 was the last category created and category 28 was created before that. But 32 is not a child category of 28.But here is the interesting part - if I do not use an array and simply pass 'cat=28' as the only argument, it displays all the posts of category 28.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try as below.

`array('cat' => 28,'posts_per_page' => 4)`

As your `WP_Query` argument.
This is the difference between providing a query string as `cat=28` directly to the query and adding a complete array with query_options so to say.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This fixed it. It's working fine now. What is the difference between "=" and "=>"?

Comment: Note the difference regarding the `''`. If you use `cat=28` as a parameter directly for the `WP_Query` class you pass a string value. The `WP_Query` class can handle both, a string which is in the format of `key=value&key2=value2` and an array of options. The construction of the array - using `=>` - is just the way you can create associative (key-value based) arrays in PHP.

Comment: Thanks a lot@malte